# Understanding `dropWhile`

Tags: haskell

In examples I've observed `dropWhile`'s behavior:

```
*Main> dropWhile (/= 'X') "AXF"
"XF"
```

But, I'm confused why `"AX"` does not return:

```
*Main> dropWhile (== 'X') "AXF"
"AXF"
```

Why does `"AXF"` return in this test?

Comment: That's exactly what it's supposed to do: stop dropping items and return the tail as soon as the predicate `(=='X')` turns out false.

Comment: takeWhile is the complementary function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`dropWhile` drops elements while the condition is true and then stops (returning the remaining elements) once the condition is false.

With `dropWhile (== 'X') "AXF"` the condition is false right away (because `'A' == 'X'` is false), so it doesn't drop anything and returns the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

The expression can be explained in English as:

> Iterate from left to right and drop characters from this string while the characters are equal to 'X'.

Implicit in this algorithm is that the function returns for the first character in the string which makes the predicate false.